# Restoring Windows XP mode

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp-mode

I have Windows 7 Ultimate installed on my laptop but use XP mode for many applications on it, is it possible to return an application in XP mode to an earlier restore point in just XP mode or does the host machine need to be restored?

I do not wish to make any changes on the host but require to either reinstall Windows virtual PC and all the applications and upgrade them slowly to the point my application fails or restore the applications back?

Any advise on this will be greatly received.

Answer (score 5):

I don't agree with Brad. It's its own isolated operating system, so you should be able to restore to an earlier point within that VM's (which is essentially what it is) OS install. Have you checked/tried doing a restore within XP Mode (Control Panel > System > System Restore tab)?

**Caveat**: Of course, you'll be at the mercy of Windows XP restore -- which even when installed on a *physical* machine still is pretty hit-n-miss.

Comment: Yup, like Uninspired said, the whole point to VMs is to isolate them from the host! You treat the guest OS as you would if it were on a physical system (ie, not a VM), so you use System Restore *in* the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Since XP mode is integrated into the host OS, you would need to return to an earlier restore point in Win7.  If you're concerned about applications and save points, it might be advisable to try using a full blown virtual environment, such as VirtualBox, where you could save the virtual machine disks to a safe place and restore from those.

Comment: odd. XP Mode as far as I've used it functions just using Microsoft's VPC with a WinXP image in it. Although I've never had a need to, I'd have assumed that one would uninstall it and re-install it if they needed to "restore" it. I must have mine set up incorrectly :-\